# QAbstractItemModel + ModelTest::rowsInserted ASSERTion problem

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qabstractitemmodel

I'm trying to debug my model (QAbstractItemModel) with ModelTest. And I can't understand one assertion.

There are two slots in ModelTest that intercept signals generated by my model.

1. ModelTest::rowsAboutToBeInserted
2. ModelTest::rowsInserted

Slot/function 1 looks like this

```
void ModelTest::rowsAboutToBeInserted ( const QModelIndex &parent, int start, int end )
{
    Changing c;
    // ...
    c.last = model->data ( model->index ( start - 1, 0, parent ) );
    c.next = model->data ( model->index ( start, 0, parent ) );
    insert.push ( c );
}
```

And slot 2 looks like this

```
void ModelTest::rowsInserted ( const QModelIndex & parent, int start, int end )
{
    Changing c = insert.pop();

    // other asserts ...

    (*) Q_ASSERT ( c.next == model->data ( model->index ( end + 1, 0, c.parent ) ) );
}
```

I don't understand dla last assertion (*). Lets assume that in my app I add 1 row.
This row is the only row that is stored in my model. So the row number would be 0.

In my model before adding the row I call

```
beginInsertRows(parentIndex, 0, 0);
```

So why does modeltest require

> model->data ( model->index ( start, 0, parent ) )

to be equal to

> model->data ( model->index ( end + 1, 0, c.parent ) )

What am I missing here ? Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind this assert is to check if first row after added ones was correctly moved. If there are some rows after inserted ones, then their data are compared. If there aren't any, your model should both in the line

```
c.next = model->data ( model->index ( start, 0, parent ) );
```

and in

```
Q_ASSERT ( c.next == model->data ( model->index ( end + 1, 0, c.parent ) ) );
```

should return invalid (empty) QVariant. If both return empty QVariant (as they should) assertion succedes, thus providing some level of error-checking even in case of no rows after currently inserted.

Comment: Thank You very much, how do You know this ? Is there some tutorial I could read about ModelTest ? :)

Comment: Unoftunately as far as i know there is no deep-understanding manual or tutorial for qt - my knowlege comes from programming for couple of years in qt and quite often going through qt sources to check how things are done.

Comment: @DavidRichardson There're official tutorials at http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/modelview.html and http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/model-view-programming.html, some info is given in the relevant classes docs, and some (surprisingly) in other classes docs (like information on proxy models in QAbstractItemModel doc). There're some blog series on the topic, also, you can search, for example for "cute model enthusiast" (yeah).