# Is properly tracking source model row movement a part of QSortFilterProxyModel's contract?

Tags: qt, model, qt4, model-view

Suppose I have a source model, within which the row movements are decorated with

```
beginMoveRows()
endMoveRows()
```

(and hence emit `layoutChanged()`).

Then, there's a [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) instance set up to filter rows of the source model.
As I get it from the sources, the source model layout changes lead to respective readjustments of the proxy model (since it listens to `layoutChanged()` signals and properly adjusts itself).

But the docs say only:

> Note: By default, the model does not dynamically re-sort and re-filter data whenever the original model changes. This behavior can be changed by setting the dynamicSortFilter property.
>
> dynamicSortFilter : bool
> This property holds whether the proxy model is dynamically sorted and filtered whenever the contents of the source model change.

My question:

- (1) does that "whenever the original model changes" include "when the rows are moved within the original model"
- (2) if so, is the order of items within the proxy model guaranteed to be the same as in the source model, and
- (3) has anyone got experience relying on the above behavior in development?
- (4) **[Extra question]** do I get it right that if I try tracking source model's rows(AboutToBe)Moved signals within a QSortFilterProxyModel subclass and call beginMoveRows/endMoveRows there (with appropriately mapped row indices), that will mess the proxy, since beginMoveRows/endMoveRows calls will try to adjust persistent indices already adjusted by QSortFilterProxyModelwhen handling onLayoutChanged source model's signal?

Thanks.

Comment: See also http://steveire.wordpress.com/2010/09/17/practicing-what-i-preach/ (the first paragraph) and https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-12299 (the last one), these somewhatadd to my worryings.

Answer (score 3):

The problems you mentioned in your comment seem to appear only when you play with number or ordering of columns, so I think your model is unaffected.

The detailed specification as to what is intended to happen is not provided, so the only alternative is to lookup the sources and hope that it will no change in future versions. After a glance into the sources I think that answers to your questions are:

- (1) Yes, qt is responding to `layoutChanged()` and `layoutAboutToBeChanged()` signals, updating it's indexes and emiting own `layoutChanged()` and `layoutAboutToBeChanged()`, so it's reacting to row moving.
- (2) Yes if you don't use sorting, just filtering. Qt in such case erases entire internal mapping and re-builds it from scratch so the data will be just as they appear in source model. Sorting of course will scatter new data around. Note that if you are using sorting and moving rows within the same parent, sorted model should not show any change.
- (3) No. I am just reading qt source and interpreting. You are free to disregard any information provided ;)
- (4) Yes, `layoutChanged()` is updating persistent indexes already, so updating it again can only mess up things.

Comment: Thanks, strange to hear that this all is so exotic, taking into account the numbers of people with Qt experience around.

Comment: Without proper documentation the only way to be sure is either to test it or check out the source. By proper documentation I mean full description, that explains what qt classes do in any circumstances that don't produce "undefined behavior" (and if they do, it should be explicitly noted in doc as well). Open source projects are usually far away from this level of detail, although the more complex the project goes, the worse it gets. Having that in mind, I must admit that qt guys are doing pretty good job documenting it.

Comment: If anyone have found it out, he will be rather reluctant to share his experience because if it's not described by Nokia, then theoretically it can change with every new version.

Comment: Yep, Qt docs are fine, but still lacking (as, it turns out, the maojority of user's knowledge is). Interestingly, it appears, I commented on the topic under one of your answers (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438539/qabstractitemmodel-modeltestrowsinserted-assertion-problem) not long ago :)

Comment: @mlvljr You were right (in mentioned comment) that infos are sometimes in suprising places in qt docs, but there is still thousand questions that only code-digging can answer - and as it happens I seem to do it quite a lot;)

Comment: Strange, seems like the bounty points somehow vanished. :(
I was sure you'll get half, and I'll get half back; or do I miss something?

Comment: I havent got any additional points - just from upvote. Perhaps something to get admin's attention?